# android keyboard push the screen up

Tags: android

some people having this problem which is when he push the button I invoke keyboard but keyboard push the whole screen up with itself. which shoud stay same at background. there is screen shot from my user.

these stuff shoud be behind keyboard, and which shoud need to see can't see coz out of screen on the out-upside

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I findout the problem is admob's ad makes it-self shown while keybord up. so I changed the ad's place which can't be distracted by keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is extremely unclear. Please be specific and descriptive. From the little I understood, you might want to look at

```
android:windowSoftInputMode
```

This link will kick it off for you: http://www.vogella.de/blog/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/

Comment: sorry for my unclear question. actually its very simple. when keyboard pop-up it slides whole screen up and I just be able to see half-bottom of screen. so I lost harf-top screen which is I actually need to see that part. I checked your link what I need is looks like "summary field".. but I actullay afraid that there is nothing wrong with the "windowSoftInputMode" coz of just some people having this problem.. I hope this a bit better and clear.. thanks for your answer

Comment: hmm, that might have to do with the different android versions out there. I wouldn't unfortunately be able to point out the exact reason for the inconsistent behavior.